# Is there some way to make core busy wait?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

I have to make a specific core busy wait.

**For example**, there are 4 cores(core_1, core_2, core_3, core_4) in the cpu, and I need to make the core_2 busy wait for t nanosecond, meanwhile the other cores still process their tasks without busy wait.

So, is there some way to achieve this?

The cpu's **model name**  is *Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz*

Comment: Depending on your OS you should be able to use [SetAffinity()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034448/obtaining-thread-core-affinity-in-c-11-through-pthreads).

Comment: I can't figure out the SetAffinity(). So can u give me more details? And i'm using linux and the kernel is 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64.

Comment: Something like if (this_cpu_id == 2) ndelay(t); ?

Comment: Why do you need one core to busy-wait?

Comment: Because I need to do some simulation, and in some case I have to make the core busy-wait to **extend the execution time** of all  processes on this core

Comment: yeah, it is just something like udelay().

Comment: Sounds like the task is to put a brake on one core and thus influence all processes running that core. Exactly what the os/scheduler will try to avoid by e.g. merging the affected processes to some other core. IMO you are targeting the scheduler directly(?)

Answer (score 1):

This code will bind your current thread to the specific core.
This is until the thread ends or you call something similar.

**This is only if your OS allows that**

It works here using `4.9.11-1-ARCH` with a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU`

See also [pthread_setaffinity_np](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

#define handle_error(msg) \
               do { std::cerr << msg << std::endl; exit(-1); } while (0)

void bindToSingleCore(int core)
{
  pthread_t thread = pthread_self();
  cpu_set_t cpuset;
  CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
  CPU_SET(core, &cpuset);

  //bind this thread to one core
  int s = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
  if (s != 0)
  {
    handle_error("Cannot write cpuset");
  }
}

int main()
{
  bindToSingleCore(1); //replace with your core 
                       //(0==first core, 1==second, ...)

  unsigned int j;
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<-1; i++)
  {
    j+=i;
    //usleep(100); //when uncommented core is not at 100% anymore..
  }
}
```

**Compile and run with something like this:**

`g++ prog.cpp -pthread && ./a.out`

**Open your favorite process- monitor and watch your core.** It should be at 100% load.

Comment: In my eyes, **pthread_setaffinity_np**  is used to bind a thread to "specific cores", but what I need is to make these cores busy-wait rather than just sleep a thread or a process.

Comment: Your question suggests you want to busy wait with one thread, on one specific core. The above code provides everything for that, except the implementation of your - not further disclosed - *busy waiting*. Usually your [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) would be a loop checking for a value change - or a specific time to elapse. 

If this is **not what you need** I strongly recommend more explanations on what you are trying to achieve *within your question* (not as a comment).

Comment: I just want to make these processes slower, but, in fact, it's the same thing. And THX very much for what U have done.